# php javascript como mostrar el valor de una tabla en un dentro de un select

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

He revisado casos similares al mio, pero no encuentro solucion.
Tego una tabla:
[image: Tabla Feed]

Cuyo valor "method" lo saco de otra tabla:
[image: tabla method]

Parte de código:

```
// escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
            $nik = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_GET["nik"],ENT_QUOTES)));
            $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM fees WHERE id='$nik'");
            if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 0){
                header("Location: list.php");
            }else{
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
            }
            if(isset($_POST['save'])){
                $fee_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["fee_date"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
                $fee      = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["fee"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
                $discount = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["discount"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
                $method   = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["method"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
                $total    = ($fee - $discount);
                $today    = $today;
                $p_id     = $p_id;
                                
                $update = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE fees SET fee_date='$fee_date', fee='$fee', discount='$discount', method='$method', updated_at='$today' WHERE id='$nik'") or die(mysqli_error());
```

Y

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Discount ($)</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="number" name="discount" value="<?php echo $row ['discount']; ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Discount" step="0.01" pattern="^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Total ($)</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="number" name="total" class="form-control" onblur="resta()" onclick="resta()" onblur="resta()" readonly >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Method</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <select name="method" class="form-control"> 
                            <option value"none" </option>
                            <?php $sql =$con->prepare("SELECT title FROM list_options WHERE list_id = 'payment_method'");
                            $sql->execute(); 
                            $result = $sql->get_result();
                            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                            { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['title']; ?> </option>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Pero en el combo box no me trae de tabla fees el valor de method, solo lo coloco si elijo:
[image: edit1]

¿Cómo hago para colocar el valor allí?
Otra pregunta mas, ¿Se puede hacer que el combobox se editable para buscar dinamicamente?

[image: edit2]

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Para lo que mencionas como primer problema, al primero de ellos (o al que mejor te parezca) agrégale la [opcion `selected`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option), puedes ver un ejemplo [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_option_selected2). Para la búsqueda revisa [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796221/creating-a-select-box-with-a-search-option) del sitio homónimo en inglés, básicamente los options del select se colocan en un [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al cargar la página, un *select* aparecerá con el valor que tenga el atributo `selected` establecido por defecto, por ejemplo:

```html
 <select name="method" class="form-control"> 
  <option value="uno">uno</option>
  <option value="dos" >dos</option>
  <option value="tres" selected>tres</option>
  <option value="cuatro">cuatro</option>
</select>
```

Entonces, lo que debes hacer es establecer ese atributo a través de php cuando estás generando el código de cada `<option>` para la opción que ha sido seleccionada en el registro que estás representando.

Para comenzar, necesitas utilizar otra variable para recorrer el conjunto de datos de las opciones del `<select>`, de manera que en `$row` se mantengan accesibles las del registro principal.

Puede ser algo como:

```php
<?php $sql =$con->prepare("SELECT title FROM list_options WHERE list_id = 'payment_method'");
  $sql->execute(); 
  $result = $sql->get_result();
  while ($rowval = $result->fetch_assoc())
  { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rowval['title'];?>" <?php echo ($rowval['title']==$row['method'])?"selected":""; ?>><?php echo $rowval['title']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

OJO: El código lo he escrito aquí mismo en el editor, puede tener algún error de sintaxis, si comprendes la explicación, podrás hacerlo por ti mismo.

Comment: Mi amigo, usted es un genio. Muchas gracias por la explicación, muchas gracias por el código... **¡aplauso! ¡aplauso! ¡aplauso!** ¡Funcionó perfecto!

Comment: Un gusto ser de ayuda :)